# Condition menu in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

In my Ember app I have a couple different menus or nabbers that I need to display depending on the section of the app the user is in. What is the recommended way of doing this? What I was attempting to do was have view in my template:

```
{{view App.NavbarView controllerBinding="App.CurrentNavbarController.nav"}}
```

And in my view I'm checking the path:

```
App.NavbarView = Ember.View.extend({ 
    templateName: function() {
        path = App.getPath('router.currentState.path');
        //change navbar
    }
});
```

That's where I'm stuck. How do I dynamically switch the views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way would be to use the router to to connect some outlets to a Nav view.

In your `application.handlebars` put a named outlet:

```
{{outlet nav}}
```

In your router, connect the outlet when you enter a route:

```
userRoute: 
  connectOutlets: (router, model)->
    # normal stuff here
    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('navbar', 'userNav', model)
  exit: (router)->
    router.get('applicationController').disconnectOutlet 'navbar'

  subRoute:
    # still has the navbar outlet connected in a subroute
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the router to set it up.

```
someRoute:
  connectOutlets: (router, model)->
     # ... normal stuff here
     App.set 'section', 'theNameOfThisSection'
  exit: (router)->
     App.set 'section', ''

  subRoute:
    # ... in the sub route, App.section will still be set
```